# "xset dpms force off" also logout from desktop

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, monitors, dpms, xset

I'm using Arch Linux with Gnome as DE and lightdm as display manager.

I have a keyboard shortcut with the `xset dpms force off` command for turning off the laptop monitor. When I execute this command display goes off but when I press any key it turns up to the lightdm login screen.

I just want to turn off the screen not log out from the desktop.

Comment: What's the `dmsg` output, right after logging back in? It would also be helpful to tell us, which resources you already know. This page, for example: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling

Comment: @Minix Here is the dmesg output: https://pastebin.com/htvR9u6x
I've read that page but didnt help me.

Comment: Did you try `xset dpms force standby` or `xset dpms force suspend`, instead of `xset dpms force off`? And did you try prepending `sleep 1` as mentioned on the page?

Comment: @Minix yes have tried all of them. Result is the same.

Comment: Related - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling

Answer (score 0):

LightDM locking is controlled by the `light-locker`. Starting it with option `--no-lock-on-suspend` and then issuing command `xset dpms force suspend` should turn off the screen without locking the session.